# Input Validation, want numbers but not strings.. code is resulting in infinite loop

Tags: c++, validation, loops, input, infinite

I am trying to figure out how to organize my code so that it will stop resulting in an infinite loop when I test it.  I put in a string, and it suddenly results in an infinite loop.

// Fill in the code to define and initialize to 1 the variable month 
    float total = 0, rain, month = 1;

```
cout << "Enter the total rainfall for month " << month << endl;
cout << "Enter -1 when you are finished" << endl;
// Fill in the code to read in the value for rain
cin >> rain;

// Fill in the code to start a while loop that iterates 
// while rain does not equal -1
if(cin.fail())
{
        cout << "You have inputted an invalid value." << endl << "Please enter an integer value for rain. (-1 to exit)";
        cin >> rain;
}
while (rain != -1)
{

    // Fill in the code to update total by adding it to rain
    // Fill in the code to increment month by one

    cout << "Enter the total rainfall in inches for month "
         << month << endl;
    cout << "Enter -1 when you are finished" << endl;
    // Fill in the code to read in the value for rain
```

Answer (score 0):

If std::cin receives input it cannot parse it will set a failbit. You can test for this with `!cin`. Don't forget to use `cin.clear` to reset the failbit after you've checked it.